# Why not use primes for random number generators?

Tags: math, random

I'm not entierly sure how rngs currently work, but I know they use time as a seed... So, why not just use a different prime number every time? As far as I know, primes are the only actual random thing known to us, so for example, every time a program asks for a random number you give him the nth prime and increase n by one. Wouldn't this be purely random? Because differences between nth and n+1th are!

Comment: Good idea. Write a function that efficiently returns the next prime number available. Also, figure out how to share that number so that all applications don't get the same prime number. (The way it works right now is they have a big list of "random" numbers, and the starting position is picked based on the current time in ticks or milliseconds.)

Comment: No, that would not be random: in fact, it would be rather predictable.

Comment: lcm generators often use a prime as their multiplicative factor....

Comment: PRNGs don't use time as a seed. That statement is overly specific (what you describe is not a property of PRNGs), and even if we generalize it you're missing the point of PRNGs. PRNGs take a seed. this seed *may* be a fresh timestamp, but the original interpretation of the seed is irrelevant to the PRNG.

Comment: What? An RNG is basically a hash function that returns you a very different number based on the seed

Comment: I look forward to the coin-flipping game based on this PRNG. Odd numbers for heads, even for tails. (and the difference between consecutive primes is hardly random either.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good idea, but there are 2 problems with this approach to building a Pseudo random number generator.

1] The security of RNGs depends in part on the inability of the attacker to know the seed that was used.  While the distance between one prime and the next is random, the sequence of primes is not random.  In other words 3 is prime, and I can't predict what the next prime will be based on the fact that 3 is prime.  But I already know that 5 is the next prime (as all low number primes are known).  Based on your algorithm, if I determine that the seeds for the last random numbers were 3, and then 5, I can guess that the next seed you will use will be 7.  So this won't work for low primes.  The list of primes from 1 to 10,006,721 is well known and published.

2] Finding primes is hard (computationally expensive). While it is less expensive for low numbers, it becomes very expensive for large primes. Most of the code that uses random numbers assumes that the number will be returned by the system very quickly, so it is used in tight loops for games, for example.  This algorithm would break those use cases.

So this would not be a good way to build a random number generator.

Comment: I was fully aware that it is hard to compute big prime numbers, and I knew this was very impractical. I see now that I worded the question incorrectly... My basic idea is that with this - you could get true random numbers.
But thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

What would this accomplish besides increasing the time to generate a number exponentially with run-time of the program?

The primes may be random .. but given the same number N i will still generate the same n+1th prime - so there is no difference to our current pseudorandom algorithms but the downtime that generating the n+1th prime is no constant time operation.

Using the time as a seed is a very convenient way of making a deterministic fast algorithm seem random. But it isn't and neither is your proposed method.

Think of the time as your n and both work pretty much the same.